# How to fix XSS vulnerabilities on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

1) I get response with html tags, for instance: This is `<b>Test</b>`

2) sometimes response may containt script (or iframe, canvas and etc.) tags (XSS), for instance: `This <script>alert("Hello from XSS")</script> is <b>Test</b>`

3) how can remove all of XSS tags (script, iframe, canvas...) except of other html tags?

PS: I can't use escape because it's remove `<b>`, `<strong>` and other tags.

Comment: See [Measures to prevent XSS vulnerability (like Twitter's one a few days before)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816224/measures-to-prevent-xss-vulnerability-like-twitters-one-a-few-days-before) and [Is there a javascript library which can be used to filter out strings for XSS attacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884209/is-there-a-javascript-library-which-can-be-used-to-filter-out-strings-for-xss-att)

Comment: There's a *lot* you need to deal with; try taking a look at http://html5sec.org to get a feel for many of the shapes and sizes XSS (and other such things) can come in. A whitelist of things you *do* allow is much safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can remove all of XSS tags (script, iframe, canvas...) except of other html tags?

*All* tags can harbour XSS risks. For example `<b onmouseover="...">`, `<a href="javascript:...">` or `<strong style="padding: expression(...)">`.

To render HTML ‘safe’ you need to filter it to only allow a minimal set of known-safe elements *and attributes*. All URL attributes need further checking for known-good protocols. This is known as ‘whitelisting’.

It's not a simple task, as you will typically have to parse the HTML properly to detect which elements and attributes are present. A simple regex will not be enough to pick up the range of potentially-troublesome content, especially in JavaScript which has a relatively limited regex engine (no lookbehind, unreliable lookahead, etc).

There are tools for server-side languages that will do this for you, for example PHP's HTML Purifier. I would recommend using one of those at the server-side before returning the content, as I'm currently unaware of a good library of this kind for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Below function could be used to encode input data to fix XSS vulnerabilities on javascript

```
/*Using jQuery : the script to escape HTML/JS characters*/
function htmlEncode(value) {
     if (value) {
         return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
     } else {
         return '';
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the tags, just do the translations.
For example, turn `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;` etc..

If you are using php, some function are for this:

[htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

[htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Can't turn < to &lt;, > to &gt; because except script tags there have b, strong, i and other and they still intact